# I accidentally changed active key for my EOS account but I have my owner key. How to reset my active key

Tags: owner-key, active-key, password-recovery

I accidentally changed active key for my EOS account but I have my owner key. How to reset my active key. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I searched around and found that GreyMass eos-voter can be used to change active keys if one has access to owner key. I did just that and now i have control of my active key.